# How can I recode an event-based variable into a value-based variable in R?

Tags: r, logging, dplyr

I am working on smartphone logging-data. Unfortunately, the information on the display is event-based, only indicating when the display is switched on or off (display_on_id1 == 1: the display was switched on at this second; == 0: the display was switched off).
I would like to have an additional variable `display_status` which has information on the current display status (0 if the display is currently switched off, 1 if it is currently switched on).
For a case with just one user I came up with a solution using for and while-loops, but this did not work when applying the code to a data frame with multiple cases.
I would also like to find a more efficient solution as I plan to apply this to a larger data frame.

This is the original data for 1 user id:

```
display_on_id1 <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA)
```

The desired data should look like this:

```
display_status_id1 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

I achieved this using the following code:

```
# replace NA to avoid problems
library(tidyr)
display_status_id1 <- display_on_id1 %>% replace_na(999)
 
for (i in c(1:length(display_status))) {
  n <- 1
  if(display_status[i] == 1) {
    while(display_status[i+n] > 0) {
      display_status[i+n] <- 2
      n <- n+1
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to solve this than using loops (dplyr etc.)?

The next issue is that I have more than one user in the data, therefore the original data looks like this:

```
display_on <- data.frame(id1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA),
id2 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA),
id3 = c(NA, 1, NA, 0, NA, NA, 1, NA, 0, NA)
)
```

the result should look like this:

```
display_status <- data.frame(id1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
id2 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
id3 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)
)
```

I tried using another for-loop to loop across the columns of display_on, but unfortunately that did not work:

```
display_status <- display_on %>% replace_na(999)


for(j in c(1:ncol(display_status))) {
  for (i in c(1:nrow(display_status[,j]))) {
    n <- 1
    if(display_status[i,j] == 1) {
      while(display_status[i+n,j] > 0) {
        display_status[i+n,j] <- 2 
        n <- n+1
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `tidyr::fill()`. Basically, you can have 2 steps:

1. fill the values down, e.g fill from the first `1` to the first non-`NA` value, same with `0`, etc.
2. since we're filling in the `down` direction, we need to replace the initial `NA`s with `0`.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

display_on <- data.frame(id1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA),
                         id2 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                         id3 = c(NA, 1, NA, 0, NA, NA, 1, NA, 0, NA)
)

display_on |>
    fill(starts_with("id"), .direction = "down") |> 
    mutate(
        across(
            starts_with("id"),
            ~ replace_na(.x, 0)
        )
    )
#>    id1 id2 id3
#> 1    0   0   0
#> 2    0   0   1
#> 3    0   1   1
#> 4    0   1   0
#> 5    1   1   0
#> 6    1   0   0
#> 7    1   0   1
#> 8    1   0   1
#> 9    0   0   0
#> 10   0   0   0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for the super fast answer, that worked perfectly!